# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

With maven, Project build successfully in local. When deploying in the server got below error. Seems this happened after adding **gson** library. earlier installed gson version "2.8.2" and then change to "2.8.6" but no success.

Java version: "8"

Maven version: "3.6.3"

Error

```
Uploaded to deployment: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/0.0.1/service-0.0.1.pom (15 kB at 105 kB/s)
Downloading from deployment: http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata 
/maven-metadata.xml from/to deployment (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Failed to transfer file http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/maven-metadata.xml with status code 500
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  40.575 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-03-23T20:24:44+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project : Failed to retrieve remote metadata /maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata maven-metadata.xml from/to deployment (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Failed to transfer file http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/maven-metadata.xml with status code 500 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

pom file added below. Please check.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <dockerfile-maven-version>1.4.12</dockerfile-maven-version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Reactive Redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Data Reactive MongoDB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Config server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Wiremock for API mocking -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Sleuth for distributed tracing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--For logging with stack trace-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ShedLock Cron Scheduler  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.30.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ShedLock Cron Scheduler Mongo Lock Provider-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>shedlock-provider-mongo-reactivestreams</artifactId>
            <version>4.30.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Springboot data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Enable connection pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Reactive Mysql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring cloud dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--Surefire-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- jacoco plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>                        
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Docker plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-image</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>tag-image</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>tag</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                            
                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>push-image</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                            
                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>                    
                    <dockerfile>Dockerfile</dockerfile>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    <buildArgs>                        <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- SonarQube Plugin -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0.2131</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>deoployment</id>
            <name>Nexus repo</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>
                http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshot Releases</name>
            <url>
                http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/
            </url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: And your pom looks like what?

Comment: @Toerktumlare pom.xml added. please check.

Comment: You have under repository releases defined that you want to deploy to localhost:8081 do you have anything running on the build server at this port?

Comment: @Toerktumlare there is no service running on that port.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting the **maven-metadata.xml**, issue resolved.

[image]